# Pushing an Object to EmberData hasMany relationship disappears

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Id like to oush object to a hasMany property of my object. When add it with an action, it shows up, and disappears when the bucket object is saved.

here is some code:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
bucket: DS.belongsTo('bucket',{
      async: true,
      inverse: "items"
    }),
});

App.Bucket = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
items: DS.hasMany('item',{
    async: true,
    inverse: "bucket"
}),
});
```

And this is how I try to push an item to the bucket, in the controller action:

```
    //add new item to the bucket
    var bucket = this.get('model');

    ////////////////
    var item = this.store.createRecord('item');
    item.set('name', name);
    item.save().then(function(resolvedItem){
      bucket.get('items').pushObject(item);
      bucket.save();
    });
```

Im using ember 1.2.0, and EmberData v1.0.0-beta.3
UPDATE: I'm using Fixture Data.

Comment: What does your server respond with on the save, is it including the item id in the list of items?

Comment: Im using Fixture Data. So I dont see any response

Comment: fund the answare here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093078/ember-data-saving-record-loses-has-many-relationships